# How grunt command works?

Tags: node.js, npm, gruntjs

What command is actually executed?
Like using `npm start` with following included in package.json

```
  "scripts": {
     "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
     "start": "node index.js"
  }
```

`npm start` runs `node index.js` behind the scenes,

Similarly, what does `grunt` run (behind the scenes)?

Answer (score 2):

When you call the Grunt task runner, it runs whatever Grunt plugins you have specified in your Gruntfile in the order you specify.

A Grunt plugin consists of a single task file. That file is essentially nothing but a Node.js script that carries out the task in question. It has access to the settings passed to the plugin and can use Grunt's file API to access the filesystem, but otherwise it's just a Node.js script.

It's not hard to write a Grunt plugin and if you're interested in learning more about Grunt it's a good way to become more familiar with it. I personally have written several static site generators as Grunt plugins and it was very useful. Grunt task file ie. `gruntfile.js` looks something like this,

```js
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  // Project configuration.
  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    uglify: {
      options: {
        banner: '/*! <%= pkg.name %> <%= grunt.template.today("yyyy-mm-dd") %> */\n'
      },
      build: {
        src: 'src/<%= pkg.name %>.js',
        dest: 'build/<%= pkg.name %>.min.js'
      }
    }
  });

  // Load the plugin that provides the "uglify" task.
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');

  // Default task(s).
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['uglify']);

};
```

when you run command `grunt uglify` basically it runs the task defined under uglify.You can find more in their get started guide [here](http://gruntjs.com/getting-started)

Comment: does running only "grunt" runs all the task ?  and where is it mentioned to run the server script lets say index.js, as mentioned above in question ?

Comment: Running `grunt` runs the default task defined in`Gruntfile.js`. If you had the cssmin Grunt plugin installed, you could call that on its own with `grunt cssmin`. Normally you would define your own tasks in the Gruntfile that call whatever plugins you need to run in the specified order.

Comment: For instance, when I build a new version of my site Irun `grunt serve` to serve it and `grunt deploy` to deploy it. Each command calls multiple Grunt plugins in turn

Comment: Thanks got your point, but from where is my server starting, like "node index.js"

Comment: That's nothing to do with Grunt. Any commands defined in your `package.json` are run in the same directory as the `package.json` file.

Answer (score 1):

grunt command executes `Gruntfile.js`, it does this through node, however it passes `grunt` configurations and functions to the plugins used inside Gruntfile. thats why you write

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
   // grunt parameter is passed from grunt-cli
   // which contains grunt functions and utilities
   // that you can use to configure the tasks etc.
});
```